# How can I change my repo access in order to push to it?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When I try to push to my repo in git, I receive the following error:

> You cannot push to myrepo. Pushing requires write access and your access is read-only

I'm using sourcetree in stash, and tried everything!

Comment: Your account apparently does not have write access... just as your error says. Check your account rights. Also, be more specific when asking questions (is this on github, bitbucket...?)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your account has the "write" access to the repository "myrepo.git". This is usually handled by the Release teams or DevOps or SA teams (Admins). Make sure to contact them and have your account added to the group that has the write access to the repository in Stash

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-permissions-776639771.html